# Building Eloquent query with "raw" column in column list

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent to build a query, passing an array of columns to the `get()` method to specify the column names that I want returning; but I'd also like to add one calculated column

```
YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(`dateOfBirth`) - (DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) < DAYOFYEAR(`dateOfBirth`)) as AGE
```

I know that I can specify parts of a `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause as `raw`, or the entire query as `raw` if I create it manually; but I'd rather use Eloquent's fluent interface to build the query.

Is there any way I can define this one column in the `SELECT` list as `raw` so that Eloquent doesn't wrap it in backticks?

**EDIT**

Alternatively, is there any way I can define the model, perhaps with a callback, of creating an age property and calculating the value in PHP when the model is populated?

Comment: Concerning the raw select I believe there's no way apart of using the `raw` method to achieve what you want.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo - I've been looking carefully through the docs/code and have come to that same conclusion myself... I may do some work on it and do a Feature Request PR to provide that functionality.... age is just one example, but I think it could also be useful for simulating `CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName)` and other similar ___calculated__ columns on a __read only__ basis that could then be used in WHERE/HAVING or ORDER BY clauses anyway without breaking pagination/OFFSET/LIMIT.

Comment: Looks like I might be able to do something by using Query\Expression objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After examining the Eloquent code, and noting that (with the exception of `*`) all entries in the fields array that's passed to the query `get()` method are wrapped in backticks unless they are `Query\Expression` objects, the solution that I came up with was:

```
$joins = [
];

$columnnames = [
    'id',
    'roleId',
    'category'
]

$calculatedFields = [
    new Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression(
        "YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(`dateOfBirth`) - (DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) < DAYOFYEAR(`dateOfBirth`)) as age",
    ),
    new Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression(
        "CONCAT(`forename`, ' ', `surname`) as fullname",
    ),
];

$modelName = 'User';

$query = (empty($joins)) ?
    (new $modelName)->newQuery() :
    (new $modelName)->with($this->joins);

$results = $query
    ->get(
        array_merge(
            $columnNames,
            $calculatedFields
        );
    );
```

Posted here for the benefit of anybody else struggling to find any documentation explaining how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

> Alternatively, is there any way I can define the model, perhaps with a callback, of creating an age property and calculating the value in PHP when the model is populated?

You want [an accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) in your model.

```
public function getAgeAttribute() {
    // do an age calculation on $this->dateOfBirth here
    return $age;
}
```

Calling `$model->age` would then spit out the result of the calculation.